# iPhone real time notification from a server, without using Apple push notification

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I'm looking for a way to get real time notification from a server in an iPhone App. I don't want to use Apple Push Notification as I have many notifications. My web service is coded in PHP, and I haven't figured out an easy way to implement this functionnality. Any idea what should I do?

Thx a lot for your help!

EDIT : I'm looking for a way to get notification only when the app is launched (otherwise, the only option IS Apple Push not.).

Comment: If you need the notifications to be received even when the app is not running, you must use Apple's Push Notification Service. Is that the case?

Comment: It's not, I just want to use it when the App is launched.

Comment: Sorry for my question that was not precise enough Pgb, and thx for your help! :)

Comment: In the app store guidelines you can read : 
5.1
Apps that provide Push Notifications without using the Apple Push Notification (APN) API will be rejected

==> So we can't do that anymore if targeting app store

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the app is running you can open an http connection from the app to the server and have the server hold it open, pushing data through it when you want. This is basically how [COMET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) works.

This will only work while your app is running. If you need the notification to happen even if the user has closed the app then Apple Push Notifications are your only option.

Comment: Thx for your answer Louis!
Yep, I read about COMET or XMPP and that looks like a solution. But would you have any example to implement it on both PHP server and Objective-c client?

It seems that it requires some kind of service to run on the server, am I right?

Comment: Yes, it requires server and client support. Sorry I don't have any experience doing this sort of thing with PHP.

Comment: Allright so after some days looking for the best solution, I came to the conclusion to use on my Debian Server:

› RabbitMQ as the message queue server, installed with the STOMP extension : http://www.rabbitmq.com/
› The following Stomp Client for PHP: http://stomp.fusesource.org/documentation/php/index.html
‹ The following Stomp Client for ObjectveC: http://github.com/juretta/objc-stomp

And I was able to make this solution works :)

Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You must use  Apple Push Notification for achieving push notifications cycle on Apple's mobile devices.