# Get changes immediately when something changed in server

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, client-server

I would like to know what is the best method to get data in iPhone as soon as a user entered or modified data in server. I can send a request for a small time interval to server to check any modifications done in server(Like Polling). I know it is very awkward. Pleas suggest a best one !!!

**EDIT**

I am not talking about push notifications. I need some Data something like while having a cricket match, when each time score updates in server I need to get that data (via XML,JSON, or any other medium) in my iPhone.

Comment: Finally got answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337985/comet-server-push-to-client-on-iphone and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589816/iphone-real-time-notification-from-a-server-without-using-apple-push-notificati

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about push notifications:  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

These let you send specific messages from your server, to devices that opt in to receiving push notifications from your app.

Comment: can i use push notification for passing huge amount of data continuously?

Comment: @rakeshNS, no, I don't think that's what they're designed for.  Not sure long polling is ideal either.  Have you looked into peer-peer?  Looks like iphone supports it:  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3621

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is known as ["Push Technology"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) (there are several variations of the same idea). In your case, what I think is best suited is "long polling". In short:

1. you poll specifying a very long timeout;
2. the server will not reply until it has some new data, so your request will be kept open as long as timeouts allow;
3. as soon as the server has got new data, it will reply, and you get the changes immediately;
4. when the timeout expires, you send a new request.

The fact of having a long poll will reduce the overhead you are worried about with "short" polling. Indeed, with short polls the idea is sending frequent requests, with a very short round-around time. This will make you send constantly requests to check for new data. With long polling you send a request only when you have got new data, or when a timeout fires (which can be several minutes).

In [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code), you will find a way to implement it.

Comment: Push notifications are better suited to a mobile device as they will use less battery than performing long polling.